# Vagrant: Set context of synced folder to prevent SELinux from complaining

Tags: linux, vagrant, selinux, vagrant-windows

Vagrant 2.1.1
Host OS: Windows 7 Pro
Guest OS: Centos 7.4

Using either the default Vagrant synced folder or nfs vagrant synced folder I keep getting SELinux errors telling me I need to change the context to `httpd_sys_content_t`. All files in the default synced folders are set to `default_t` context and all files using nfs sync are set to `nft_t`.

files are always default_t context
`config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant'`
files are always nfs_t context
`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",  type: "nfs"`

I have tried to change the files context the normal way using `fcontext` and `restorecon`, but `restorecon` just fails silently.

How can I set the context of synced files/folders to avoid SELinux errors??

I've tried using `:mount_options`, but they're ignored.
Example:
`config.vm.synced_folder "./www", "/var/www",  type: "nfs", create: true, id: "sites", mount_options: ['vers=3', :udp, :nolock, :noatime, 'context=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0']`

Maybe I'm adding the context in mount options the wrong way??

Answer (score 0):

You must use rsync for vagrant synced folders because setting SELContext via sync_folders is not supported as it a limitation of vboxfs. So do something like this in your vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "guest/sync/location", "/host/sync/location", :owner => "root", :group => "root", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: [".git", ".DS_Store"], rsync__args:["-avz", "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'"]
```

This workaround assumes you have persistently and recursively set httpd_sys_content_t using semanage and restorecon as per this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/409464/permission-denied-in-vhost-document-root/409488#409488).

EDITED: 11/3/2018 
Sadly the above solution doesn't actually sync files because rsync doesnt really work with a widows host. Here are my findings and conclusion on a workaround:

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9827#issuecomment-435622888